# Postgres describe of aggregate function returning type modification value of -1 for user defined type

Tags: postgresql

I've created an aggregate function with the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rtrim(mychar) RETURNS mychar
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mycharrtrim'
            LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mychar_max( mychar, mychar ) RETURNS mychar
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mychar_max'
            LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mychar_min( mychar, mychar ) RETURNS mychar
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mychar_min'
            LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE AGGREGATE MAX( lzchar ) ( 
    SFUNC  = mychar_max,
    STYPE  = mychar,
    SORTOP = > 
);
CREATE AGGREGATE MIN( mychar ) ( 
    SFUNC  = mychar_min,
    STYPE  = mychar,
    SORTOP = < 
);
```

The **mychar** is a type that is defined with 2 type modifiers. The first type modifier is the length of the string and the 2nd is the CCSID of the string since we are tying to simulate a zOS string. I then create at table like the following:

```
create table t1 (c1 mychar(20, 1208), c2 char(20));
```

Within my C code I then try to do a describe of the following statement:

```
select c1, max(c1), max(c2) from t1 group by c1;
```

The describe returns fine, however, when I try to retrieve the data from the describe using the following code:

```
char *colName = PQfname( result, hvNum );
int   colTmod = PQfmod( result, hvNum );
int   colSize = PQfsize( result, hvNum );
Oid   oid     = PQftype( result, hvNum );
Oid   tblOid  = PQftable( result, hvNum );
```

For the first column I get the expected values (colName, colTmod, oid and tblOid). For the 2nd column (max(c1)) it returns **max** as the colName (which I expected), it also correctly returns the correct **oid**. However, for **colTmod** it returns **-1**. Is there something that I need to do to get the proper colTmod value returned in this case? For the max(c2) column which is a native char it correctly returns everything as expected including the **colTmod** as **24**. There must be something I am doing incorrectly that results in my implementation of the char or the aggregate function not returning the type modification value correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% certain, but I am pretty sure that the result of an aggregate function has no type modifiers.

I tried your experiment with a column defined as `numeric(7,2)`, and like you I got -1 for `PQfmod` when I queried the maximum.

`numeric`'s `max` aggregate is defined using `numeric_larger`, which is defined as:

```
Datum
numeric_larger(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    Numeric     num1 = PG_GETARG_NUMERIC(0);
    Numeric     num2 = PG_GETARG_NUMERIC(1);

    /*
     * Use cmp_numerics so that this will agree with the comparison operators,
     * particularly as regards comparisons involving NaN.
     */
    if (cmp_numerics(num1, num2) > 0)
        PG_RETURN_NUMERIC(num1);
    else
        PG_RETURN_NUMERIC(num2);
}
```

So it is as simple as it can get and returns one of the input values.

If type modifiers are not preserved there, I'd guess they are never preserved in an aggregate.

Comment: Thx, for the response Laurenz. I'll have to verify this on the weekend. I think what I saw before was that either the typmod or size would be correct for at least the (var)char types. I'll have to check again and also see what happens with numeric as well.